# Parameter invalid when trying to save image and then upload to BLOB storage

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am having some problems when trying to save the following image and upload it to my Blob storage in windows azure. 
Since the debug mode is not working for azure I would like to know if you can tell me where am I passing an invalid parameter in the following method :

```
byte[] decodedBase64Sring = Convert.FromBase64String(stringToEncode);

MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(decodedBase64Sring);

Bitmap aBitmap = new Bitmap(ms);
                    aBitmap.Save("c:\\photo1.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                    blob.UploadFile("c:\\photo1.jpg");
```

Comment: What do you mean by debug not working?

Comment: More details would be helpful like where exactly in your code you're getting the error, detailed error information, what kind of application it is (web, desktop, windows 8).